# Define a role to only save drafts even when editing published content

Tags: nodes, workflows

I bet this is a nerd doubt (sorry) but after searching all I find are more complicated/advanced questions and not 'the basic one'.

I'm creating a 'basic editor' role that can send content (node) that won't be published until the admin updates it to 'published'. I got that by unticking the 'published' checkbox in the required content types publishing options*. This role can only mess (create, edit, delete) with its own content.

Now the 'basic editor' user can send content and it stays as unpublished until admin changes it to the published state. The problem now is **once the node is published the 'basic editor' user can edit it and the node will be public with the new amendments without an admin revision**. And I need an admin to check the changes before they go public. I've been messing with a bunch of modules and could not figure out to solve it with any of them: workflow, publishcontent, override_node_options, content_moderation...

I'm sure this should be a common request and, so far, has a simple, probably out-of-the-box solution. Appreciate your help.

---

- Being picky I'd prefer to have all node forms without the 'published checkbox' and have them published by default for admins and as a draft by rest of roles, but that's not so important.

Comment: Content moderation should cover this case even with default configuration: there should be a 'draft' unpublished state and a 'published' one.The transitions between them should be set in order to: a basic user create a node in draft\waiting to review. An admin publish them. The basic user edit the node and put again in "waiting to review". At that point, the "old published" node is visible to everyone, until the admin publish the new revision. Doesn't it work?

Comment: Ty. It explains the procedure but not the details of how to accomplish them. In Drupal forum site I was addressed to check https://www.lullabot.com/articles/basics-drupal-revisions-and-content-moderation

I'll give it a read and heck if I can solve it the way you suggest. Ty!

Comment: Hi! I've installed Content moderation (along with Workflow) and set 'Content editor' role to let them Create New Draft .

You were right that works with default configuration. Only that I had to give permission to 'Create New Draft' (Move content from Draft, Published states to Draft state.), otherwise they could not post at all, not even a draft.
Thanx!